# How Linux links driver with device file?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I have a question about device file and drivers, based on ULK hence 2.6.11 kernel. My understanding is the following:

1. When user does syscall open() on some device file, at some point kernel will ask inode of the device file for the read/write function.
2. The device file was created by udev, based on devices in /sys folder, meaning the inode of the device file should have i_fop field pointed to functions that knows how to talk to the device, such as read() and write(). Meaning each device file's inode->i_fop field should point to different file_operations struct.
3. If so, the device driver will be providing these read/write function, maybe the complete file_operations struct, including read/write/ioctl, etc.

now , ULK says (in the description of open() syscall for device files) "sets the i_fop field of the inode object to the address of either the def_blk_fops or the def_chr_fops file operation table, according to the type of device file." And that means all block device files have the same read/write function, then how can a user talk to different devices?

I also checked the device_driver struct, and indeed, there are no place for file operation functions, so how exactly an open syscall performs its job using a device specific driver then? And where do device specific operation function live, if not in device_driver?

Comment: Answered on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787779/2762678